# wxPython Frame disable/enable?

Tags: wxpython

I have created a wx.Frame(lets call it mainFrame). This frame contains a button on it, when the button is clicked, a new frame(lets call it childFrame) is created.

I want to know that how to disable the mainFrame when childFrame is created and enable the mainFrame again when childFrame distroyed/closed?

Regars,

Comment: It looks wx.Frame has not the MakeModal method anymore...
[https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal) So you can implement the shown snippet (from the link) into your child frame and it works in combination with accepted answer from @Alex.

Answer (score 10):

May be you want something like this:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.NewId(), "Main") 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open a child")
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

        self.Layout()

    def on_button(self, evt):
        frame = ChildFrame(self)
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.MakeModal(True)

class ChildFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Child")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, evt):
        self.MakeModal(False)
        evt.Skip()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you do not need another frame but a modal dialog e.g.

```
import wx

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
mainFrame = wx.Frame(None, title="Click inside me")
def onMouseUp(event):
    dlg = wx.Dialog(mainFrame,title="I am modal, close me first to get to main frame")
    dlg.ShowModal()

mainFrame.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, onMouseUp)
mainFrame.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(mainFrame)
app.MainLoop()
```